# Problems with categories displaying in Magento

Tags: magento, categories

I have set up a load of categories in magento, and all but two are showing up in the category list. They are set as active and display in nav.

When I tried renaming each of these categories they show up fine, but this isn't really suitable. I have tried clearing all indexes and cache but with no luck.

If it helps, the categories are named "offers" and "top sellers".

Comment: can you show the category hierarchy on admin panel

Comment: Do you have something that hides the categories with no active products? any other customization made to the categories in the template?

Answer (score 0):

There are a few things that can cause a category not to show up:

- If the category is not set to active it will not show
- If the category does not have any products in it, it will not show
- If the category is not enabled for that store view (make sure that it's enabled for the site you want)